# Matching string against multiple values of an object with regex?

Tags: regex, powershell, object, string-matching

```
    $Options = @{

   a1 =@('Fish','Hotdog','BBQ Sauce','Cheeseburger','Trains go fast')
   b1 = 'Beef'
   b2 = 'Birthday cake'
}

$Dinner = 'Fish'

if($Dinner -match $Options.'^a+\d$'){$FoodOutput = 'Dinnertime!'}
elseif($Dinner -match $Options.b1){$FoodOutput = 'Weekend! Enjoy!'}
elseif($Dinner -match $Options.b2){$FoodOutput = 'Happy Birthday!'}
else{$FoodOutput = 'No Food! save money!'}

$FoodOutput
```

Is it even possible to match a string with multiple sub-options? The goal is that if $Dinner match any string within $Options.a* it would trigger the $FoodOutput 'Dinnertime!'

Comment: Try `$dinner -match ($Options.a1 -join '|')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment added by @AdminOfThing solved my problem. Since I'm not sure how to mark this as solved based on a comment, I used this as an escape :P

```
$Options = @{

   a1 =@('Fish','Hotdog','BBQ Sauce','Cheeseburger','Trains go fast')
   b1 = 'Beef'
   b2 = 'Birthday cake'
}

$Dinner = 'Fish'

if($Dinner -match ($Options.a1 -join '|')){$FoodOutput = 'Dinnertime!'}
elseif($Dinner -match $Options.b1){$FoodOutput = 'Weekend! Enjoy!'}
elseif($Dinner -match $Options.b2){$FoodOutput = 'Happy Birthday!'}
else{$FoodOutput = 'No Food! save money!'}

$FoodOutput
```